# Include raw FASTA files (.fas) in R packages

Tags: r

In building R packages for eventual CRAN submission, how can raw FASTA files (.fas) be added?

FASTA files don't belong in the /data directory nor in /inst/extdata, which is for CSV (.csv) files, etc.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You can insert every possible file in `inst/extdata`. I have done this in several packages.

Comment: '/inst/extdata' isn't just for CSV files. Not sure where you got that idea from. You can put any "raw" data there you like.

Comment: @MrFlick Just used CSV as an example as it is a common data file format.